# Determine if Listbox index change was from refresh or mouse click

Tags: c#, listbox, mouseclick-event, selectedindexchanged, onmouseclick

I have a Win Forms listbox whose contents are refreshed every few seconds. The listbox displays messages stored in a database to which people can respond - it's a customized instant messenger app. When the refresh happens the selectedindex automatically changes to 0 which is a problem if I have the 6th message selected and I am trying to responding to it. How can I determine if the index change is a result of the refresh or a mouse click on the listbox and then stop the selection change if it's not a mouse click?

Comment: Use a bool variable.  Set it to *true* when you refresh, back to *false* afterwards.   Now you know.

Comment: In the event handler for the timed refresh can you not store the selected index there and then re-assign selected item after the refresh?

Comment: I think I have the answer. Kind of similar to Niff's comment. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution to my question. I wasn't sure how to do event handlers so I researched that. I added an event handler to the MessageListBox.click event. This event handler sets a property called selectedIndex and is the only place that sets this value. In the refresh method I set the MessageListBox.SelectedIndex to this value after the Update/Refresh call.